# Double "in", is it natural?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, idiomatic-language

I made up a sentence:

> She sold the house that she lived in in her childhood

Obviously, these 2 "in" relate to different words in the sentence, but is it natural and idiomatic?

I've heard natives use similar structure of the sentence countless times but with 2 different prepositions e.g. "She hated the man she was married to in her twenties".

Should I rephrase my sentence because I have 2 identical prepositions in a row?

Comment: No, it doesn't sound odd.

Comment: If youve made the sentence, is there any reason not to use "during"?

Comment: It does sound clumsy to me but, as James says, you can change the sentence in many ways to avoid it - _the house where she lived_ or _when she was a child_, for example.

Comment: It might sound a bit more odd if we had ***three*** consecutive instances of ***in*** here, but it could still be perfectly grammatical - if her mother was a "live-in" domestic servant, so she she "lived **in**" along with her mother, **in** (within) that house, **in** (during) her childhood.

Answer (score 1):

It is not really a problem, the two "in"s are different in function. The first is part of the phrasal verb "live in", and the second is a prepostion.

However, as there are very simple ways to avoid this, you can improve your sentence either by using "during" (which is a more precise preposition of time) or in formal writing "the house in which she lived".